# pointing to local drive Office.FileDialog fDialog = Application.get_FileDialog(Office.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogSaveAs)

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I have created Excel add in project in c# (.net 2010). My project saves excel file to sharepoint.I have used

```
Office.FileDialog fDialog = Application.get_FileDialog(Office.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogSaveAs)
```

I have set  `fDialog.InitialFileName` to sharepoint URL. But some time save as dialog pointing to the local drive instead of pointing to sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you allready got the answer.. But the problem is mostly on the local client. Sometimes the WebClient service has to be restartet to make the windows explorer see a  SharePoint document library as a folder.

The other problem can be an access problem. If the site isn't a Trusted site, windows explorer cannot send the user token through.